# What did Peer Gynt look like?

Tags: scandinavian-languages, henrik-ibsen, peer-gynt

Is there a good description of the physical looks of Peer anywhere in [the play Peer Gynt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer_Gynt)?  I assume he looked like the "default" for "adventurer" types. (I automatically think of Oliver Queen in the *Hong Kong* flashbacks, or of Sawyer in *Lost*.)

Or is there any description of Peder Olsen Hågå, whose life was the inspiration for Ibsen's poem/play?

(My brain is a permanent lulz producer and after hearing The Offspring, I just imagined Peer Gynt in the Hall of Trolls...stalked by Snorkmaiden.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Details are scarce.

The script for the play introduces Peer Gynt with the description:

> [PEER GYNT, a **strongly-built youth** of twenty, comes down the pathway. His mother, ASE, a small, slightly built woman, follows him, scolding angrily.]

At the beginning of Act IV, we have another not-super-helpful description:

> (Peer Gynt, a **handsome** middle-aged gentleman, in an elegant travelling-dress, with a gold-rimmed double eyeglass hanging at his waistcoat, is doing the honours at the head of the table.)

Later, during their conversation, he mentions that his "hair was slowly growing grizzled," and it's also mentioned that he puts on his glasses halfway through.

At the beginning of Act V:

> [PEER GYNT, a vigorous old man, with **grizzled hair and beard**, is
> standing aft on the poop. He is dressed half sailor-fashion, with
> a pea-jacket and long boots. His clothing is rather the worse for
> wear; he himself is weather-beaten, and has a somewhat harder
> expression.]

There isn't much else to go on, but we at least have a rough idea about to how Peer looked at each part of the play.

Ibsen himself helped adapt the work for the stage, so it's possible he was involved in the casting and costuming. It turns out that the first ever actor for the role was a guy named [Henrik Klausen](https://no.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henrik_Klausen). Here's what he looked like at one point in the play:

[image]
[(Wiki Commons)](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/86/Henrik_Klausen_som_Peer_Gynt_-_1876_-_Ernst_Emil_Aubert_-_Oslo_Museum_-_TM.T01439.jpg)

An [earlier picture](https://cdn2.picryl.com/photo/1876/12/31/henrik-klausen-som-peer-gynt-1876-ernst-emil-aubert-oslo-museum-tmt01434-cropped-3f5a1a-1024.jpg) of a younger Peer Gynt shows that he had dark hair.

---

I couldn't find any information about the appearances of Peder Olsen Hågå or Per Laurissen Hågå, and the [memorial statue](https://no.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peer_Gynt#/media/Fil:S%C3%B8dorp_kapell_-_Minnesmerke_over_Per_Olson_H%C3%A5g%C3%A5.JPG) in the *Per Gynt Gården* is actually some abstract depiction, not a humanesque one.

Comment: When you're writing plays, there are good reasons for not specifying the physical details of the actors' appearances too closely — you want various actors to be able to play the roles.